# C# PorpertyChanged in viewmodel is null when using sockets

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, asyncsocket

I am new to C# and MVVM so I might be doing something wrong.
I created a Window (called LoginMenu) and added a userControl for a chat taking 1/3 of the window. I then created a ViewModel and a Model for that Chat userControl. My Chat model is getting updated by a socket when it receives any message coming from a client. It looks like my Conversation field is getting updated in the model but the PropertyChanged in my ChatViewModel is null.
My Conversation Textbox was getting updated properly before I started using sockets.
I read online that it could be because my UI thread wasn't getting updated since it's not running on the same thread as my socket. This feels unlikely since even my ChatViewModel is not getting the right PropertyChanged event.

Here's some code snippets:
LoginMenu.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:LoginMenuVM />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="mainMenuOnlineTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:MainMenuOnlineVM}">
        <views:MainMenuOnline DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="chatTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ChatVM}">
        <views:Chat DataContext="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<views:Chat Grid.Column="1"></views:Chat>
```

LoginMenu.xaml.cs :

```
public partial class LoginMenu : Window
{

    public LoginMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new LoginMenuVM();
    }

}
```

LoginMenuViewModel:

```
public class LoginMenuVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private SocketService socketService = new SocketService();
    private User user = new User();
    private ChatVM chatVM = new ChatVM();
```

...

```
    public void ConnectUser(object obj)
    {
        if (NameIsIncorrect())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username is incorrect!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            AssignName(potentialName);
            socketService.Start(ipAdress);
            try
            {
                string authentification_informations = user.Name;
                socketService.SendDemand(authentification_informations);
                {
                    chatVM.connectSocket(socketService, user);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Chat.xaml:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewmodels:ChatVM />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<DockPanel Background="White">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="name" Text="Name" Background="LightGray" />
    <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="50" Name="messageEntry" Text="{Binding ChatBoxMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TextBox}}}" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Conversation" Text="{Binding Path=Conversation, Mode=TwoWay}" />

</DockPanel>
```

ChatViewModel:

```
public class ChatVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private static SocketService socketService;
        private static User user;
        private static Chat chat;

        public string Conversation
        {
            get { return chat.Conversation; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string _chatBoxMessage = "Enter Message";
        public string ChatBoxMessage
        {
            get { return _chatBoxMessage; }
            set
            {
                _chatBoxMessage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ChatBoxMessage");
            }
        }

        public RelayCommand<object> SendMessageCommand { get; set; }

        public ChatVM()
        {
            chat = new Chat();
            SendMessageCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(SendMessage);
        }

        public void SendMessage(object obj)
        {
            if (socketService != null) {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ChatBoxMessage))
                {
                    socketService.SendDemand(user.Name + ":" + ChatBoxMessage);
                    MessageBox.Show(Conversation);
                }
                else {
                    MessageBox.Show("You can't send empty or only white space messages.");
                }
            }
            else {
                    MessageBox.Show("You can't send messages since you're not connected.");
            }
        }

        public void connectSocket (SocketService socketServiceTemp, User userTemp)
        {
            user = userTemp;
            socketService = socketServiceTemp;
            chat = socketService.GetChat();
            chat.PropertyChanged += Conversation_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private void Conversation_CollectionChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Conversation = chat.Conversation;
        }

       protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Chat.cs:

```
public class Chat : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _conversation = "Test";
        public string Conversation
        {
            get { return _conversation; }
            set
            {
                _conversation = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

SocketService.cs:

```
private void TreatAnswer(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    int messageReceivedInInt = socket.EndReceive(ar);
    //Transform Bytes received to string
    App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
    {
        chat.Conversation += messageReceived;
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    });
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    socket.BeginReceive(byteMessage, 0, 2048, SocketFlags.None, TreatAnswer, socket);
}
```

I have tried using

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        });
```

in both Chat.cs NotifyPropertyChanged and ChatViewModel NotifyPropertyChanged.

As mentionned above, when I add a breakpoint to the NotifyPropertyChanged of the ChatViewModel, the PropertyChanged is null. Is there anyway I can make this code work? This feels like a small mistake but I can't find it.

EDIT :

I found the problem. I had to call :

```
chat.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(Conversation_CollectionChanged);
```

Inside the SendMessage function of my ChatVM to fire the proper event.

Comment: A little hint: Try to avoid using so much of `static`-variables. They can produce strange issues, when you work with multiple threads on it. Each object should have his own fields and dont share it with other objects.

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling the UI that it which instance of ChatVM to be used by the chat template

LoginMenuViewModel.cs

```
private ChatVM chatVM = new ChatVM();

Public ChatVM ChatVMProperty // We need a property to bind
{
    get { return chatVM; }
    set { chatVM = value; 
          /* Call Notify Property Changed if 
           you are assigning after constructor 
           getting called */ 
        }
}
```

LoginMenu.xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="chatTemplate" DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:ChatVM}">
    <views:Chat DataContext="{Binding ChatVMProperty}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```